# elasticsearch wont start - ShardNotFoundException

Tags: elasticsearch

my elasticsearch server was improperly shutdown.
Upon restart elasticsearch service wont start. 
Apparently this is because of an shard problem.
My question is how do i solve this? 
should i delete the indice "tor"? 
or is there a turn around?
I tried to reassign the shard with no success.
Here's the log entry where i think the problem resides.

```
    RemoteTransportException[[Anais][xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9300]
    [indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; 
    nested: ShardNotFoundException[no such shard];
    Caused by: [tor][[tor][4]] ShardNotFoundException[no such shard]
```

**EDIT:** I think this as to do with the fact that i only have one node

Answer (score 0):

I can't figure it out how but the problem is solved. 

Maybe elastic search was executing some kind of slow operation making it unavailable... 

if this makes any sense a appretiate a comment.